spl-token Metaplex adding metadata issues
can anyone help with this error. happens after i try run my javascript that i compiled from typescript, to add metadata to my existing solana token.
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
Error updating metadata: Error: failed to get info about account 35a57yb7LfwQcAj5QTkAw3M9T62wGiZjXc1aiz2j9WGg: TypeError: fetch failed
at Connection.getAccountInfo (/home/SENSITIVE-INFO/Desktop/SENSITIVE-INFO/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6252:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Object.getAccount (/home/SENSITIVE-INFO/Desktop/SENSITIVE-INFO/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-rpc-web3js/dist/cjs/createWeb3JsRpc.cjs:25:21)
at async fetchMetadata (/home/SENSITIVE-INFO/Desktop/SENSITIVE-INFO/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/dist/src/generated/accounts/metadata.js:40:26)
Here is the typescript.
const fs = require('fs');
const {
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  clusterApiUrl,
  Keypair,
} = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { updateV1, fetchMetadataFromSeeds } = require('@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata');

// Import the createUmi function from the Umi bundle defaults
const { createUmi } = require('@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults');

// Create a new Umi instance to interact with the Solana blockchain
const umi = createUmi('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');

async function updateTokenMetadata() {
  try {
    // Connect to the Solana mainnet
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');

    // Specify your token's mint address
    const mintAddress = new PublicKey('SENSITIVE-INFO');

    // Load the payer's Keypair from a file
    const payerSecretKey = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/home/SENSITIVE-INFO/.config/SENSITIVE-INFO/id.json', 'utf8'));
    const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(payerSecretKey));

    // Fetch the initial metadata for the token
    const initialMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint: mintAddress });

    // Update the metadata attributes
    const updatedData = {
      name: "SENSITIVE-INFO",
      symbol: "SENSITIVE-INFO",
      uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SENSITIVE-INFO/SENSITIVE-INFO/main/token.json",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500, // This is just an example value
      creators: null,
      ...initialMetadata,
    };

    // Load the update authority's Keypair from a file
    const updateAuthorityPath = './updateAuthority.json'; // Path to updateAuthority.json file
    const updateAuthoritySecretKey = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(updateAuthorityPath, 'utf8'));
    const updateAuthority = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(updateAuthoritySecretKey));


    // Initiate the metadata update transaction
    await updateV1(umi, {
      mint: mintAddress,
      authority: updateAuthority, // You need to define updateAuthority
      data: updatedData,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    console.log("Metadata updated successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating metadata:", error);
  }
}

// Call the function to update the token metadata
updateTokenMetadata();


The error says:
Error: failed to get info about account 35a57yb7LfwQcAj5QTkAw3M9T62wGiZjXc1aiz2j9WGg

This means the account at address 35a57yb7LfwQcAj5QTkAw3M9T62wGiZjXc1aiz2j9WGg does not exist. This means you're providing an incorrect public key, or one of the accounts that you need (either the mint or the metadata) does not exist. Be sure to create the metadata before attempting to update it.
